# jQuery chaining to create concatenated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, syntax, chaining

Pretty simple, but I'm doing something wrong.  I want to do a nice clean chain here, rather than declaring a var and then concatenating it:

```
the_function( null, null, 
   $( this ) // START string I'm passing as a parameter
   .attr( 'data-href' )
   .html( '|foo:' + event.var ) 
); // END string I'm passing as a parameter
```

I realize that `.html()` is invalid here, what is correct?

Comment: What is your desired outcome, and why do you want method chaining to do string concatenation?

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "jQuery chaining". Chaining is simply the ability to immediately call a method on a value that was returned from a previous call.

Comment: @user1689607 that's just nit-picking. You are operating on the jQuery Object so you could as well call it jQuery chaining...

Comment: @Christoph: I  disagree. I believe plenty of people think chaining is a feature that is caused by some jQuery magic. Anyway, it makes as much sense to call it jQuery chaining as it does to say I'm going to McDonald's to do some McDonald's eating.

Comment: @user1689607 I agree, many people don't even know that jquery is just plain javascript. Please if you nitpick next time say: chaining is a technique of subsequently calling a function-property of the previously returned object. Values have no properties and javascript has no methods in the classical sense.

Comment: @Christoph: Values absolutely have properties if they are an object or a primitive with an object wrapper. If a value that does not allow for methods is returned, then obviously you can't chain a method call. And JavaScript absolutely has methods [as defined by ECMAScript](http://es5.github.com/#x4.3.27).

Comment: @user1689607 You are confusing a lot of technical terms here. What you mean are (primitive) data types which all have an object wrapper per se in Javascript (and thus properties). And you can have function properties which you could call mothods, but they are not exclusively bound in javascript and thus not methods in the classical sense as I already told.

Comment: @Christoph: I'm not confusing any terms. I am talking about an object or a primitive value that has an object wrapper. It is incorrect to say that all primitive types have an associated object wrapper. The "classical" definition of method isn't relevant when we're talking about a specific language that defines what a method is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Huh? do you mean to do something like this

```
the_function( null, null, 
   $( this ) // START string I'm passing as a parameter
   .attr( 'data-href' ) +  '|foo:' + event.var);
```

What you had

```
$( this ).attr( 'data-href' ) // returns a string.. it doesn't have a html method
```

Comment: @Brian Sometimes it's most obvious that we overlook :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to accomplish but here are some notes:

- you can use .data() method for data- attribute
- you can't use .html() on .attr(), you need to use html() on
  $(selector)

So, basically, you could use this:

`$(this).html('|foo:' + event.var).data('href')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the outcome is that you want, but if you really want method chaining, you could chain the native `.concat()` method to the string.

```
the_function( null, null, 
   $( this ).attr( 'data-href' )
            .concat('|foo:', event.var) 
);
```

---

Or separate `.concat()` calls if you really dig the chaining.

```
the_function( null, null, 
   $( this ).attr( 'data-href' )
            .concat('|foo:')
            .concat(event.var) 
);
```